# The getAllSites times out every time I call it

Tags: yodlee

I am new to the Yodlee API.  Doing my first integration with the Aggregation API.

Have a couple questions for the pros:

I am wondering what the best practices are for allowing a user to select which bank they use?  I was thinking about using an autocomplete textbox that queries the searchSite API.  The service returns a ton of results though and seems to be slow.  I'd like to have a local copy of all the sites but whenever I call the getAllSites API it times out.  What have some of you done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, getAllSites should not be timed-out until you have set some time out explicitly. As this query is trying to get the complete list of sites which Yodlee supports; please expect delay in response. I would suggest you to get it as a request in background, store the list of sites and traverse through it for your auto complete text box suggestions.
I would also suggest you to increase the time out(if you have set for your solution/application) or wait till you get a response for this API call.